# Pass custom argument to rails event model callbacks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, model, callback, arguments

Very simple question but was unable to figure this out.
Is it possible to do like:

```
  after_create    :log_activity(my_var)
```

So I could write 1 method that handles all the actions ( destroy,save,update)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not possible to pass variables to callback method. Reason is simple as callback methods are called by rails stack and when it will call callback method, it did't know what to pass in callback method.

Comment: This is no longer accurate, as of Rails 4.2 (and probably earlier). See my answer below for a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55763940/4454732

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that:

```
after_create Proc.new{ log_activity(my_var) }

def log_activity(my_var)
 :
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is new in Rails 4.2 vs. when you asked the question was asked, but this works:

```
after_create -> { log_activity(my_var) }
```

I wonder if the question you're really getting at is about the scope of `my_var`.  What is your intention with my_var?

Comment: Would you mind explaining why/how this fixes the problem, and how the accepted answer may be wrong? Please keep in mind, this is from an older version of the software and may not support newer features

Comment: Done. Thanks, Derek.

Answer (score 0):

If I right understand you than in my practice was case to update user's balance on create or destroy salary. so try this code:

```
class Salary < ActiveRecord::Base

after_create  { |action| action.update_user_balance(1) }
before_destroy { |action| action.update_user_balance(-1) }

def update_user_balance(val) #val can be +1/-1
  user = self.user
  user.update(balance: user.balance + self.sum * val)
end
```

Hope this will help you! :)